# Online Permutation/Bijection Calculator

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, symmetric-groups, online-resources

Does anyone know of an online permutation calculator (permutation in the sense of $S_n$)? I found one a while ago (I am pretty certain the website had the word "banana" in the title), but I can no longer find it. I just need to do things such as verifying that I properly calculated, e.g., $(12)(23)(12)(23)$, etc.

Comment: [Wolframalpha has this capability](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=perm(1+2)(2+3)(1+2)(2+3)).

Comment: You can also use the magma online calculator: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Comment: But be aware that Magma (and also GAP) composes permutations from left to right, but it is probably more common to compose them from right to left.